# Unanswered Questions-Near The End Of An Era

Tags: discussion

I undertook a mission in the spring of 2019 for this sight-eliminate the [Unanswered Questions](https://chess.stackexchange.com/unanswered) list down to 0.
When I began, there was an absurd total of 75.

Now we are down to 23 questions, with a former record of 18 or 19 at some point. Nearly all of them are from this year (erm, unproductive summer I suppose plus a lot of them are programming questions, so there's also that). It took a lot of upvotes and answering to get there!

Only 5 remain that are not from this year. Once put to rest, all that will remain are from this year. It's almost the end of an era for unanswered questions.

I encourage everyone to go look at the list and see if they can answer any of the unanswered questions. The less there are, the better.

However, some of [them](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8966/from-a-full-board-to-a-pawn-endgame-in-the-shortest-possible-number-of-half-move) seem to have no possible answer (one that is absurdly difficult to find) and are on-topic. What should be done about such questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should be done about such questions?

[Fermat's Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) was proposed in 1637 and only solved in 1994. If the field of mathematics can survive for 357 years with an unanswered question so can chess stack exchange.

I say, leave them for future generations to struggle with.